# make Bluetooth Discoverable

Tags: android

I want to make Bluetooth Discoverable , is there any way and does android allow my application to do this ?

I have found a link for this , but I do not know how can I do this .

```
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#BLUETOOTH_DISCOVERABILITY][1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By this code your device will be discoverable for 300 sec

```
 if (mBluetoothAdapter.getScanMode() != BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE) {
        Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
        startActivity(discoverableIntent);
    }
```